# Application of Girsanov's theorem

Tags: stochastic-processes, finance, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Given a Brownian motion $W(t)$ under $P$ and the stochastic process $\hat{W}(t) := W(t) - \int_{0}^{t}\theta(s)ds$ which is a Brownian motion under an equivalent measure $Q \sim P$.

The stochastic integral with respect to $dW(t)$ is 
$$\int_{0}^{t}dW(s) = W(t).$$
However, can one integrate with respect to $\hat{W}(t) + \int_{0}^{t}\theta(s)ds$ instead? I.e, 
$$ \int_{0}^{t} dW(s) = \int_{0}^{t}(d\hat{W}(s) + \int_{0}^{t}\theta(s) ds)$$

Does the expression above make sense, and if so, should it be evaluated as

$$\int_{0}^{t}d\hat{W}(s) + \theta(s) ds ?$$

Concretely, I have the following dynamics under P:

$$ X(t) = X(0)\exp(t\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(s)ds + \int_{0}^{t}\sigma(s)dW(s)). $$

I want to describe the dynamics under Q~P under which $\hat{W}(t) = W(t) -\int_{0}^{t}\theta(s)ds$ is a Brownian motion.

Making the substitution seemingly gives 
$$(Q): X(t) = X(0)\exp(t\int_{0}^{t} \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(s) ds + \int_ {0} ^{t} \sigma(s)(d\hat{W}(s) +\theta(s)ds)): $$